# How to maintain one data structure in a server across multiple clients?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I'm trying to create a matchmaking server with node.js & Socket.io server side and react-native client side
When I open two simulators, both connect fine, but the point at which I log the contents of the matchmaking queue, it only contains each respective user, instead of both. for instance when the second user connects, both users should show up in the logged contents of the queue but don't.

Server.js:

```
io.on("connection", socket => {
  console.log("a user connected..." + "\n");
  const queue = new LobbyQueue();
  socket.on("addPlayer", username => {
    if (queue.hasUser(username)) {
      console.log("user already in queue...");
    } else {
      console.log("New user joined: " + username);
      queue.enqueue(username);
      socket.join("lobby");
      const players = queue.getAll();
      console.log("Players in queue: " + "\n" + players);
      io.sockets.in("lobby").emit("players", players);
    }
  });
)};
```

I expect both users to be logged in the console when the second user connects and joins the room. however, only one username (the username from each respective client) is logged. it seems that the queue objects aren't universal to both clients. also, is there some relevant terminology for this subject?

Answer (score 0):

Your `queue` is being created on the client, so each client with have their own queue, independent of each other. It sounds like you want to hold the queue on the server, so maybe something like this (but add safety checks as needed)?

```js
const queue = new LobbyQueue();
sockets.on('connection', (socket) => {
  socket.emit('connected', { users: queue.getAll() });
  socket.on('addUser', user => queue.enqueue(user));
  socket.on('getUsers', () => queue.getAll());
});
```

Comment: You're right @Jim - sorry! But still you have to pull the queue outside the scope of the connection, otherwise you'll get a new queue for every connection